# Catching different kind, when leaving a site (onunload)

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to catch some different kind of actions when a user leaves a site with

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    doSomething();
}
```

I want to split them into two different types. The first one would be that the user closed the browser, the tab, or left the site by typing in a new web address into the browser.

The second one would be if the user leaves the site, because he was sent to another one by a button press, which is laying on my page.

I want to distinguish between these two options, and want my Javascript to act differently based on which action has been done. Is there any handler to catch this?

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 Page visibility API might help.
    But currently it needs vendor prefixes like "webkit","moz";

```
document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", function(){
    console.log("Page visiblility : "+ !document.webkitHidden);
});
```

I'm not sure about closing the browser though.